# GIMP: opening dicom files

Tags: gimp

I am trying to open a dicom file (.dcm). All files I tried yield an error saying `transfer syntax 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70 is not supported`. What can I do?

Comment: You could search for what else might open them… Gimp doesn't claim to be able to open .dcm file. Oddly, fileinfo says it can, but Gimp doesn't. It also says these apps can open .dcm - https://fileinfo.com/extension/dcm

Comment: Going out on a limb, perhaps find a utility that will alter the images so they have a different [transfer syntax](https://www.dicomlibrary.com/dicom/transfer-syntax/). Otherwise, it might be necessary to use another viewer.

Comment: Of couse GIMP is ought to open DICOM files. It is even included in the file open dialog and you can export to .dcm as well. The latest features even include DICOM meta data editing, as written in the 2.10 release notes. A plug-in called file-dicom.exe is installed by standard and invoked when I try to open a .dcm file. So I did't ask, what other DICOM capable apps there are, but why I can't open these .dcm as exported by standard med programs like  OnDemand3D and HDX Will. So why down vote a legitimate question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says GIMP doesn't support the transfer syntax of the file. The source code of GIMP 2.99.6 (latest available version) shows that DICOM support is provided by file-dicom.c:

```
  switch (element_word)
    {
    case 0x0010:   /* transfer syntax id */
      if (strcmp("1.2.840.10008.1.2", (char*)value) == 0)
        {
          do_toggle_endian = FALSE;
          implicit_encoding = TRUE;
        }
      else if (strcmp("1.2.840.10008.1.2.1", (char*)value) == 0)
        do_toggle_endian = FALSE;
      else if (strcmp("1.2.840.10008.1.2.2", (char*)value) == 0)
        do_toggle_endian = TRUE;
      break;
    }
```

Transfer syntax `1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70` isn't found in this or any other file in GIMP's source code.

As already suggested by Tetsujin and Anaksunaman, the only workarounds are to either use another application to open the file, or use an utility that converts it to one of the three transfer syntaxes GIMP does support:

> 1.2.840.10008.1.2 Implicit VR Endian: Default Transfer Syntax for DICOM
>
> 1.2.840.10008.1.2.1   Explicit VR Little Endian
>
> 1.2.840.10008.1.2.2   Explicit VR Big Endian

Seeing that the image transfer syntax is for lossless JPG I would strongly recommend finding another application. All three transfer syntaxes GIMP supports are for standard lossy JPG, so the usability of the resulting image in medical context is questionable.

Comment: It's on the records as an open issue with the dev team. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/7063 Their best best bet for better support would be to start using the GDCM library. Still, someone with time and interest, needs to do the necessary work for that to happen.

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. GIMP is an OS tool, developed and maintained by individuals according to the needs of the userbase. These needs don't extend to handling high-quality medical imagery. If your job requires handling this kind of material, what actually _needs_ to happen is that your employer provides you tools for the job. Not being able to open these images when needed should be more than enough to present your employer a valid business case for investing in appropriate software.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but the wording of my last comment was actually a citation of a GIMP project maintainer regarding this issue. --- Anyway, I do have other tools to open these files, like 3D Slicer. Not to mention the list that Tetsujin linked to. I am just very used to using GIMP for almost any kind of images and ran into this trying to open these files. So it doesn't. Ok.

Comment: Yap, I read that. There's also the other quotable from Wormnest... "I have no experience in C++, nor a real interest in dicom. I do not plan on looking into this anytime soon"... maybe he does find the contributor. Good thing you have the tools - I was getting pissed off _for_ you :-D I've seen often enough situations where the employee actually isn't allowed necessary tools. Getting used - I know exactly the feeling... I played with PSP in my springtime years, later on with Photoshop for years. That was many years ago and I'm _STILL_ not used to GIMP way of doing things!